# Access strings inside a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

A Python list has `['12:30','12:45']` and I want to access the `'12:30'` for the first iteration, and on the second iteration I should get `'12:45'`.

```
my_list=['12:30','12:45']
for each_value in my_list:
    print(each_value[0])
```

The expected result is `'12:30'` but the actual output is `'1'`.

Comment: `each_value` represents a single string from the list, and you are indexing into that string instead of the list. Print `each_value` instead, and drop the `[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You should write it as:

```
>>> my_list=['12:30','12:45']
>>> for each_value in my_list:
...     print(each_value)
...
12:30
12:45
```

`each_value` is a string `"12:30"`, `"12:45"` as you move on. So calling `[0]` on a string will you get the first character of that string which is `"1"`.