# Accessing the strings inside a list and combining into dictioanry

Tags: python-3.x

I want to access the strings which are inside my list

```
my_list=['12:00','12:30','13:00','13:30','15:00','15:30']
```

I have tried the below code, however I am getting 1 and 1 as the answer.

```
for i,my_list in enumerate(my_list):
    my_list_start=my_list[i]
    my_list_end=my_list[i+1]
```

The expected result is:
I have to combine the two values from a list. For example,
my output should looks like :

```
[{"start":12:00,'end':12:30},{'start':12:30,'end':13:00},
 {'start':13:00,'end':13:30},{'start':15:00,'end':15:30'}]
```

Comment: Why there is no `'13:30','15:00'` in output?

Comment: It's the same problem you had in your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275987/access-strings-inside-a-list

Comment: I dont need to combine 13:30 and 15:00 because I get the '15:00' from some other iteration

Comment: That is accessing the first element,but now I have to combine the values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access strings inside a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275987/access-strings-inside-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

```
for i,my_list in enumerate(my_list): #my_list is refering the the string at i not my_list
    my_list_start=my_list[i]
    my_list_end=my_list[i+1]
```

You can't redefine the list that you are iterating over otherwise it will cause weird issues. In this case it is being redefined to a string and it is accessing the first number in that.

Do this instead:

```
for i,item in enumerate(my_list): # notice ``ITEM`` instead of my_list (we don't want to rename my_list)
    my_list_start=my_list[i]
    my_list_end=my_list[i+1]
```

Or don't even bother with enumeration:

```
for idx in range(my_list):
    my_list_start= my_list[idx]
    my_list_end=my_list[idx+1]
```

Then I am assuming you put it into a dictionary elsewhere because you don't really have any logic here to do that.

Comment: I have tried with and without enumerate but I am getting error in two cases.When I try with enumerate ,for example   for i,value in enumerate(my_list):
...     new_start=value[i]
...     new_end=value[i+1]
...     print(new_start)
...
1
2
0
0 I am getting this output.

Comment: @bala as I specifically stated in my answer. Don't change the variable inside the loop to the variable you use with enumerate. That is the ***string*** at the given index not the ***list***